# How can i make 3 images fit the whole screen?

Tags: html, css

i got the following problem:
I am trying to fit 3 images in my whole screen. Each image should be at 33% width and centered(that only the center of the image is displayed.)
this is my code:

```
<div class="fluid-container">  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
  <img src="images/skills.jpg" alt="Bitte benutze einen anderen Brwoser">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
       <img src="images/kontakt.jpg" alt="Bitte benutze einen anderen Brwoser">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
     <img src="images/lebenslauf.jpg" alt="Bitte benutze einen anderen Brwoser">
   </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
img  {background-size: cover;  background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

Comment: try img{with:100% ;}

Comment: try adding  `.img-responsive` bootstrap class in img tag

Answer (score 0):

They aren't background images so background styling won't work, instead of using  tags inside of your columns, give the columns IDs and set background images for each, then you can consult something like w3schools for all background styling methods and play around.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look 
http://codepen.io/santoshkhalse/pen/QGrrBz

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="fluid-container">  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="row">
  <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/106/719/original/vector-abstract-blue-wave-background.jpg" alt="Bitte benutze einen anderen Brwoser"class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
     <div class="row">
      <img src="http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/518164-backgrounds.jpg" alt="Bitte benutze einen anderen Brwoser"class="img-responsive">
</div>
</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
     <div class="row">
     <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/106/719/original/vector-abstract-blue-wave-background.jpg" alt="Bitte benutze einen anderen Brwoser" class="img-responsive">
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this looks better than mine so far. one more question, how do i get the full height of the screen. (it should be responsive) height 100% doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

@Erwin Ivanov You are suppose to add responsive bootstrap classes for different devices. please check following code for it:

```html
<div class="fluid-container">  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  <img src="images/skills.jpg" alt="Bitte benutze einen anderen Brwoser" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
       <img src="images/kontakt.jpg" alt="Bitte benutze einen anderen Brwoser" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" >
     <img src="images/lebenslauf.jpg" alt="Bitte benutze einen anderen Brwoser" class="img-responsive">
   </div>
  </div>
```